# is there a specific order in which a control's data bindings update and its events/commands execute

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Take, for example, a `ComboBox`. Bind the `SelectedItem` to a viewmodel property and bind the `SelectionChanged` event to a command in the viewmodel (or even handler in code-behind). When an item is selected, is it safe to assume that the `SelectedItem` always updates the bound property **before** the command bound to `SelectionChanged` event is executed?

Comment: What good would the changed event be if it were fired before the change was actually made?

Comment: I would of thought so. `SelectionChanged` is in the past tense and implies it's already changed.

Comment: Yes. It is a .Net Framework convention that events occurring "during" an operation have their names suffixed with *"..ing"*. It is safe to assume that `SelectionChanged` occurs after "selection changed", otherwise it'd be called `SelectionChang`**`ing`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally i would say no , because you can't bough for all events and dependency properties. 
In this case of The SelectedItem DP and the SelectionChanged event the order is as you described .

Firstly by naming convention SelectedItem and Selection**Changed** , Changed meaning after the SelectedItem was changed.

Secondly , learn how to use some sort of reflector , i recommend : [DotPeak](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/)

I took a peak in the **Selector** class (ComboBox inherits from Selector) code , there you can see the SelectionChanged event raised from within the callback on the SelectedItem DependencyProperty.